# What are purposes of `texlive-games` package?

Tags: texlive, examples

In the process of fresh install of `texlive-most` on my new system I noticed that package `texlive-games` would be installed. I have not found good examples of usage `texlive-games`. So, what are the main purposes of this and can you please provide examples of the documents made with this package?

Comment: This is a group of packages for typesetting things related to games: chess, crosswords, go, sudoku. It also has two games (Tower of Hanoi and reversii) which are run using TeX. For chess you can look at the [tag:xskak] tag for some examples.

Comment: How to run these games?

Comment: You do not run those games. The packages are mostly used to show game states.

Answer (score 1):

> How to run these games? – danielleontiev 3 hours ago

- Locate `hanoi.tex` on your system. For me it is `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/plain/hanoi/hanoi.tex`
- go into folder
- run `tex hanoi` and `dvipdf hanoi`
- the results of game will be in `hanoi.pdf`

If you prefer to play yourself, try https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/jeopardy/example